# Помогите с разбором тестового задания C#, wpf, nhibernate, ioc, mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inversion-of-control

Выполнял тестовое задание при поиске работы. Результат моей работы никому не понравился, поэтому прошу помочь с разбором.

Суть такова: написать приложение которое выводит список компаний и список сотрудников выбранной компании. У каждого сотрудника есть ФИО, адрес, тел, должность. 
Реализовать добавление/удаление сотрудника и компании, редактирование. Все сохранять в базе данных SQLite, использовать NHibernate, WPF, паттерны MVVM, IOC.

Кратко что сделал я:

- Реализовал классы Employee и Company, для каждого из них соответственно EmployeeViewModel и CompanyViewModel;
- Список сотрудников с их данными и список компаний вывожу в два DataGrid, поэтому реализовал универсальный шаблон ViewModelCollection, так для одного списка получается `ViewModelCollection<EmployeeViewModel, Employee>()` 
  [полный текст шаблона ViewModelCollection<>](https://github.com/MicroKoder/WPFTestApp/blob/master/MyWPFApp/ViewModel/ViewModelCollection.cs).
  Этот класс связывает коллекцию моделей с view, пробрасывает уведомления CollectionChanged во view и обратно, для хранения коллекций моделей завел классы CompanyPool и EmployeePool, соответственно для хранения списка компаний и списка сотрудников выбранной компании.

Теперь реализация шаблона Invertion of control так как ее понял я:

- Завел два интерфейса для списка сотрудников и списка компаний, ICompanyDomain, IEmployeeDomain, (все время хотелось что-нибудь объединить, но что-то не додумался как сделать единый интерфейс для двух списков, а может оно и не надо было):

  ```
  interface ICompanyDomain
  {
  void Add(Company company);
  void Update(Company company);
  void Remove(Company company);
  ICollection<Company> Load();
  }
  ```

Работает это так - класс CompanyPool содержит ссылку на интерфейс ICompanyDomain, через который загружает и редактирует список компаний когда надо, а вся реализация интерфейса содержится в классе DBCompanyDomain, этот класс уже через NHibernate работает с базой данных.
[Интерфейсы и их реализации](https://github.com/MicroKoder/WPFTestApp/tree/master/MyWPFApp/Domain)

А вот какой код класса MainWindow получился:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();          
    }

    private void dataGridCompanies_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Company company;
        if (dataGridCompanies.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            try
            {
                //получаем ссылку на выбранную компанию
                company = (dataGridCompanies.SelectedItem as IViewModel<Company>).GetModel();

                //загружаем список сотрудников выбранной компании
                dataGridEmployees.DataContext = new ViewModelCollection<EmployeeViewModel, Employee>(EmployeePool.Instance.GetEmployeeList(company.Id));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //на случай если в таблице был выбран PlaceHolder
            }
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //-------- Подключение к БД --------------------
        //-- настройки подключения в файле hibernate.cfg.xml
        var cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.Configure();
        var sessions = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();

        // ----------- Создаем и привязываем домены для работы с базой данных --------------------
        EmployeePool.Instance.employeesDomain = new DBEmployeeDomain(sessions.OpenSession());
        CompanyPool.Instance.companiesDomain = new DBCompanyDomain(sessions.OpenSession());

        //------------ загружаем список компаний, связываем его с ViewModel а ViewModel с View
        dataGridCompanies.DataContext = new ViewModelCollection<CompanyViewModel, Company>(CompanyPool.Instance.GetCollection());

    }
}
```

Весь код проекта тут (visual studio 2017):
https://github.com/MicroKoder/WPFTestApp

Comment: Косяки мне выписали такие 1. MVVM реализован неверно 2. IoC вообще нету 3. в БД сразу писать нельзя (а как можно то?)

Comment: Ну конечно, MVVM это, в первую очередь, привязки и команды, а не Button_Click

Comment: Причем я бы сказал MVVM тут практически нет. Вы нарушаете самую важную вещь, а именно - "код не должен знать о view элементах". Вы пишите в итоге `dataGridCompanies.SelectedItem as IViewModel<Company>`. По правилам MVVM - вы должны работать с коллекциями и теми объектами, что в коде, так, будто у вас вообще нету View части (вашего XAML). Для грамотной реализации используются привязки (binding) из View, заместо click - команды и куча других вещей. У вас все по старому, как на обычных WinForm например, но с щепоткой MVVM...

Comment: ясно, с MVVM  я облажался, но на просторах интернетов миллион всяких статей посвященных этому шаблону, на деле являющиеся мусором.

Comment: Вот [отличный курс](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/wpf-mvvm-entity-framework-app) на эту тему, построение приложения от начала и до конца по всем канонам.

Comment: @Bulson, он походу отроскомнадзорен (AWS?) - не грузится из РФ.

Comment: @Сергей, странно,  у меня грузится, курс называется `Building an Enterprise App with WPF, MVVM, and Entity Framework Code First`

Comment: Ну может быть какие-то местные проблемы, но загрузил ток в торбраузере)